Breakpoint is not hit when running test in pytest in test explorer of VS code, but only for venv env
I have been strugging with this problem: I am using python 3.7.16 on Windows and vs code as IDE. I have set up two virtual environments: one using Anaconda and another using venv. The two environments are supposed to be identical since my goal is to use the latter to replace the former.
Now the problem comes: when I am launching the program by setting launch.json using either environment, I am able to debug my program and it stops at the breakpoints, which I assume means both environments have the correct dependencies installed (I have verified that it is indeed the desired environment that has been activated). But when I am trying to debug my test cases in test explorer in vs code with pytest, i.e., when I click the debug test button nextd to the test cases discovered (the test discovery process also succeeds which I assume means the path is also set up correctly), when I am using the conda env my breakpoint is hit but when I am using venv env, the breakpoint IS NOT hit and the test finishes just like when I hit the button run test. When I am checking the output window from python, I didn't see any output difference when running under two environments. So how can I debug my test cases under venv?
Thank you for your help!
Cheers,
Wei
